# Java - Saving values for use in a different function

Tags: java

So this is a stupid dbeginner's question.

I wrote a function that checks if a specific game move is legal (Reversi). The function must only return a boolean true/false value.

Later, in a different function, I actually make the move (makeMove function). In this function, before making the move I call the isLegal function to make sure the move is legal.

Now, when the isLegal function decides the move is legal, it would help me to save the specific info that lead to the decision, and use it in the makeMove function. I have no ideah ow to do that. I tried writing a function that will store the relevant data, and then send it back, but there's an obvious provlem with scopes here.

So here's the relevant code from isLegal:

```
else if(board[k][l]==player){relevantDirection=false; isLegal=true; ReversiPlay.saveLegalMove(direction, k, l);}
```

Then the problematic saving function:

```
 public static int[] saveLegalMove(int direction, int row, int column){ 

    if(direction==0){  //get info from function
        return legalMoveData;
    }
    else{  //save legal move data
        int[] legalMoveData = new int[3];
        legalMoveData[0]= direction;
        legalMoveData[1]= row;
        legalMoveData[2]= column;
        return null;
    }
}
```

And lastly, I try calling the stored data:

```
int[] getSavedInfo = ReversiPlay.saveLegalMove(0, 0, 0);
```

I'm sure there's a very simple way of pulling the variables direction+k+l... anyone?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a clearer example:

```
    public static boolean A(int a){
    ...calculations...
    int x = [value]
    int y = [value]
    return false;}
public static void B(int a){
    ...calculations...
    boolean h = A(3);
    [here I'd like to know what x,y were]
}
```

Comment: You need to make an object (like a Move object) that has those properties. Then when you need them, you can get them from your move object.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more this fragment: `it would help me to save the specific info that lead to the decision, and use it in the makeMove function. ` ?

Comment: Andrew thanks, is there no other way? I'm supposed to use only things we learned in class, and we didn't learn that yet. Eel Lee, here's a better description from my edit: Let's say I have function A that stores some info into x,y,z, and returns true/false. I want to use x,y,z in function B. (I cannot request that function A return x,y,z because it needs to return only true/false). So how can I get to those specific x,y,z from function B.

Answer (score 0):

```
 else {  //save legal move data
        int[] legalMoveData = new int[3];
        legalMoveData[0]= direction;
        legalMoveData[1]= row;
        legalMoveData[2]= column;
        return null;
    }
```

This part doesn't save anything. It stores the values to a local variable and returns `null`.

An approach would be to make a `Move` object that contains the data you need:

```
public class Move {

    private int direction;
    private int row;
    private int column;

    ...
}
```

Your `isLegal` method would only tell you if the move is legal. Then you can use that same `Move` instance to make the move.

```
if(ReversiPlay.isLegalMove(move)) {
    ReversiPlay.makeMove(move);
}
```

There is no need to explicitly save the move; you already have that information inside the `Move` object instance.

**UPDATE**

Based on your edit, perhaps it is better to return an object instead of a `boolean` from `A`:

```
public static boolean A(int a) {
    ...calculations...
    int x = [value]
    int y = [value]
    return new MyObject(x, y, false);
}

...

MyObject myObject = A(someValue);
```

Then you can query `myObject` to see what the value of the flag is.

**UPDATE**

You mentioned you aren't allowed to use objects. If so, instead of making the same calculations however, you can extract that logic into its own method and then call that. That way you won't have to duplicate logic.

Comment: The info I want to store is not the move itself. The info I want to save will help me in the makeMove function, but the move itself is passed specifically into the function. I am looking for a way to use other info from one function (isLegal) in another function (makeMove), without having to make the same calculations over again that are made in isLegal.

Comment: I edited the last part of the question, I think it's clearer that way.

Comment: I see, thanks, I thought there might be a simpler way (as I am not allowed to use objects since we didn't learn about them in class yet). I'll just make the same calculations again in the second function. Thanks for your help though, now I know how to do it for myself!

Comment: @user2996797 Ah, I wasn't aware that you weren't allowed to use objects. Instead of making the same calculations however, you can extract that logic into its own method and then call that method. That way you won't have to duplicate logic.

Comment: Oh I haven't thought of that.. thanks, that would be much better.